# How to map between push parser and pull parser

Tags: parsing, design-patterns, observer-pattern

I have implemented a pull parser that reads a data stream and emits tokens on selected content via a callback handler. This abstract technique is also known as *observer pattern* (with the callback handler also known as observer) and used for instance in SAX for parsing XML.

The contrary design pattern (is there a name for it?) is to pull the next data token as used for instance in XML parsing with StAX.

One can easily map to a push parser by looping a pull parser:

```
// push
parser.parse( callback: handler );

// pull
while( token = parser.next ) {
    handler(token)
}
```

But how do I map a push parser to a pull parser?

Comment: I don't fully understand what you are asking but my initial thought is that the terms push and pull are just definitions. An algorithm always takes input and produces output. So in this case the reverse of pulling from a data stream and pushing tokens would be pulling tokens and pushing a data stream. AFAIK an algorithm pulling pushed data makes no sense, the same way that talking about an algorithm generating inputs from outputs makes no sense.

Answer (score 2):

To adapt a push parser into a pull parser, you have to collect several (all ? depending on what is being parsed and the order of the elements being pushed) into `Event` objects.  And then allow those `Event`s to be pulled.

We can use XML as an example and adapt a SAXHandler into a StAX parser.  We also have to implement the methods for XMLStreamReader for iterating over the StAX `XMLEvent`s.

I've never used StAX but it looks like it stores the current state in the `XMLStreamReader` object.  Each call to `reader.next()` updates the state and the returned values from `reader.getName()` and `reader.getText()` etc are updated accordingly.

We can do this several ways from parsing the entire thing in memory first, then iterating through what we've stored in memory, to more complicated techniques such as using multiple threads to parse the XML and block reading the next tag until the user calls `next()`.

For simplicity, I'll just show storing everything in memory

```
class SAXHandler extends DefaultHandler implements XMLSTreamReader {

       //Stax Event objects
       List<XMLEvent> events = new ArrayList<>;
       int counter=0;
       //Stax current tag name and text data updated with calls to next()
       private String name, text;


       @Override
      //Triggered when the start of tag is found.
      public void startElement(String uri, String localName,
                        String qName, Attributes attributes)
                        throws SAXException {

          //create a new XMLEvent for the start of the new tag
          XMLEvent newEvent = ....

          events.add(newEvent);


       }
      //other SAX methods implemented similarly
      ...
```

Now for the StAX methods:

```
    @Override
    public XMLEvent next(){
         if( !hasNext() ){
             throw NoSuchElementException();
         }
         counter++;
         XMLEvent next =events(counter);
         //update our content 
         this.name = next.name;
         this.text = next.text;
         ... 
         return next;
    }

     @Override
     public boolean hasNext(){
         return counter < events.size();
     }

    ...
    @Override
    public String getName(){
          return name;
    }
    @Override
    public String getText(){
          return text;
    }
 }
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for the detailed example. Pre-Parsing everything just to get a list of events is no efficient option, so I suppose I have to dig into multithreading.

Comment: I've done it before and it is VERY error prone.  Using my example, you can replace the `new ArrayList<XMLEvent>` with a `new LinkedBlockingQueue<XMLEvent>(1)` which will force the thread doing the SAX parsing to block if there is already list already has something in it.  And change `next()` to blocking pop the list using `take()`.  But then you have to worry about handling the End of file (there's nothing else to take so you have to stop blocking). And error handling if you never finishing parsing the file for somereason (IO exception, or user stops calling next() before it's done etc)

Answer (score 1):

What I think you are looking for is Control Inversion, which is not easy in languages which are tied to a stacklike execution model.

C is not quite welded to execution stacks, so you could do this with the (deprecated) Posix [`getcontext/setcontext/makecontext`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696799/functions/setcontext.html), or slightly more portably with threads.

In other languages, it is easier, if no less mind-bending. See Scheme's `call/cc` primitive, this piece of Lua [ancient history](http://lua-users.org/wiki/FunWithCoroutines), or take a look at Python generators (although the latter is not able to invert control without help from the function whose control is to be inverted.)